# How do I set laravel test to go to site name instead of localhost

Tags: php, laravel, testing, phpunit, integration-testing

I am trying to write some tests for an application.  I have the server set up on MAMP going to dev.myappnamehere.com.

When I run a test (based off of Laracasts Integrated) it fails because it is looking for the route

```
 http://localhost/p/profile
```

But what it needs to go to is

```
 http://dev.myappnamehere/p/profile
```

How can I change that so it does not default to looking for the localhost and instead goes to the correct path?

I attempted to change this in the test but got nowhere and I was unable to located an answer through googling.

```
 <?php

 use Laracasts\Integrated\Extensions\Laravel as IntegrationTest;
 use Laracests\TestDummy\Factory as TestDummy;

 class ExampleTest extends TestCase {

/**
 * A basic functional test example.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function testBasicExample()
{
    $this->visit('/')
    ->see('Login')
        ->type('example@example.com', 'email')
        ->type('password', 'password')
        ->press('Login')
        ->seePageIs('/p/profile');
  }

}
```

Comment: Post your phpunit test code?

Comment: Did you set `config.url` in `config/app.php` to `http://dev.myappnamehere`?

Comment: Actually I just solved it.  In LaravelTestCase.php there is a baseUrl, once I changed that the test looked in the correct spot

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So shortly after I asked I stumbled on the answer.  In

```
 LaravelTestCase.php
```

there is a function called

```
  baseUrl()
```

which sets the url it looks for.  Once I changed that it looked in the correct spot.  That file was part of the laracast testing that I loaded in.

Comment: You don't need to change LaravelTestCase.php. Like @Dallin said, just replace $baseUrl.

Comment: @alvaropaco sorry, maybe that wasn't clear but that is what my answer is saying, change baseUrl()

Answer (score 10):

From Laravel 5.4 the `$baseUrl` method doesn't seem to work anymore

Also, trying to set the url dinamically with `\Config:set('app.url', 'http://dev.myappnamehere')` doesn't work either, as it seems that Laravel caches the root url

A way to set a custom root url is:

```php
\URL::forceRootUrl('http://dev.myappnamehere');
```

Comment: `URL::forceRootUrl` saved my day for debugging a webhook in Laravel with phpunit and Ngrok!

Comment: Saved my day too! I could not run any unit test, because I had to install Laravel inside a sub-directory and the resulting paths messed up the tests routing.

Answer (score 6):

For Laravel 5,
In the `tests` directory there should be a file called `TestCase.php`. In that file is a property `$baseUrl`. Update the value to your desired url. For example change

```
protected $baseUrl = 'http://localhost';
```

to

```
protected $baseUrl = 'http://dev.myappnamehere';
```

Answer (score 3):

Most likely you need to change a domain root in your existing `request()`.

```
$domain = 'homestead.test';
request()->headers->set('HOST', $domain);
```

test

```
\Log::debug(request()->root());
```

> http://homestead.test

Answer (score 0):

Change the APP_URL in your .env file from localhost to your desired URL.

Ex:
APP_URL=http://myproject.test

Answer (score -2):

The below instead

```
$this->visit('http://dev.myappnamehere')
```